# undefined method `paginate' for nil:NilClass when searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm doing some basic crud work in a Rails 3.2.20 app where I track LostCalls.  I have everything setup and working but when trying to implement a search method my controller is throwing a NilClass when I try to paginate.

Here is what my model, view, and controller looks like.

**lostcalls_controller.rb**

```
def index    
     @lostcalls = LostCall.report(params[:search])
     respond_to do |format|
         format.html do
           @lostcalls = @lostcalls.paginate(:per_page => params[:per_page] || 1, :page => params[:page]).order('call_date ASC')
         end
         format.csv { send_data LostCall.to_csv(@lostcalls) }
         format.pdf do
          pdf = LostCallPdf.new(@lostcalls)
          send_data pdf.render, filename: "lostcalls",
                                type: "application/pdf",
                                disposition: "inline"
         end
       end
   end
```

**lost_call.rb model**

```
class LostCall < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :call_date, :call_details, :entered_by, :facility_id
  belongs_to :facility

  scope :by_facility, lambda { |id| where(facility_id: id) }
  scope :search_between, lambda { |start_date, end_date| where("call_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date.beginning_of_day, end_date.end_of_day)}
  scope :search_by_start_date,  lambda { |start_date| where('call_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', start_date.beginning_of_day, start_date.end_of_day) }
  scope :search_by_end_date, lambda { |end_date| where('call_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', end_date.beginning_of_day, end_date.end_of_day) }

  def self.report(search)
    search ||= { type: "all" }

    results = results.by_facility(search[:facility_name]) if search[:facility_name].present?

    if search[:start_date].present? && search[:end_date].present?
      results = results.search_between(Date.parse(search[:start_date]), Date.parse(search[:end_date]))
    else
      results = results.search_by_start_date(Date.parse(search[:start_date])) if search[:start_date].present?
      results = results.search_by_end_date(Date.parse(search[:end_date])) if search[:end_date].present?
    end
    results
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h3>Lost Call Log</h3>
<%= render 'search' %>
<%= render 'results' %>
```

**_search.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag lostcalls_path, :method => 'get' do %>  
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag "search[start_date]", params[:search].try(:[], :start_date), :placeholder => 'Start Date', :class => 'input-large search-query ', id: 'start_date_select' %>
        to 
        <%= text_field_tag "search[end_date]", params[:search].try(:[], :end_date), :placeholder => 'End Date', :class => 'input-large search-query', id: 'end_date_select'   %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= select_tag "search[facility_name]", options_from_collection_for_select(Facility.order(:facility_name), :id, :facility_name, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :facility_name)), prompt: "Any Facility" %>   
      </p> 

      <p>
        Results Per Page
        <%= select_tag "per_page", options_for_select([["10", 10], ["25", 25] , ["50", 50], ["100", 100], ["All", 100000]], selected: params[:per_page]), class: "span1" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => 'btn' %> <%= link_to "Export to CSV", lostcalls_path(params.merge(format: "csv")), :class => "btn btn-info" %> <%= link_to "Export To PDF", lostcalls_path(params.merge(format: "pdf")) , :class => 'btn btn-warning' %> <%= link_to "New Entry", new_lostcall_path, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>

      </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**_results.html.erb**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Call Date</th>
      <th>Facility</th>
      <th>Call Details</th>
      <th>Entered By</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @lostcalls.each do |l| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= l.call_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %></td>
        <td><%= l.facility.try(:facility_name) %></td>
        <td><%= l.call_details %></td>
        <td><%= l.entered_by %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'View', lostcall_path(l), :class => 'btn btn-info btn-mini'%></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @lostcalls, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

I have similar functionality being used in another reporting controller to track actual calls (not LostCalls) and it works fine.  I think there's a problem with my report class method but I'm having a hard time debugging it even with better errors.

So to summarize, the index view will work if I get rid of the `LostCall.report(params[:search])` and do  a `LostCall.order("call_date ASC") and it will paginate properly.  It seems that the report method is broken and returning nil in the model.

If I need to refactor my questions or provide additional information please let me know.  I appreciate any help that you can offer.

Thanks and good day!

**Update**

Thanks for the feedback guys, I forgot to initialize the results variable.  So a simple `results = scoped` fixed it.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the results variable isn't initialized in the report method?

Comment: You're right.  I was writing this half-asleep (not a good practice) and forgot to initialize.  So I added `results = scoped` to initialize and now things are working :)

Answer (score 0):

Your report method will return nil whenever you try to acces index page because it does not sent intially any params which you are using in report method.
suppose if params[:start_date], params[:end_date] and params[:facility_name] name are not present then report method will return nil.

Either fix report method or send default value in params from your form.you can add condition in index action also to fix this.

Also first line of report method is not needed as you are not using it, as you have added condition on each line.